# Mysql - when changing a row in a column, change the other rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I can't seem to find an answer to my problem, but I got a database where I would like to change the row in a column to affect all the other rows in the same column, is this possible?

(I can't post an image because of reputation?! - but my column is called Active and there's 2 rows right now - the first one has the value 'ja' and the second one is NULL)

'ja' and NULL are the only two values I will be using, so when the second row is set to 'ja', I would like the first row to change to NULL. But as I can see it might not be possible, but if anyone knows more than me, I would be very happy!

It's Mysql database I use sql queries and php.

Comment: Show us your sql queries.

Comment: You could fix it to your queries. But it wouldn't be the direct way to do that.

Comment: at the moment i don't even know how to approach this. My best quess would be: UPDATE tablename SET Active=:value WHERE Id=:Id , and then maybe an if statement if that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd keep things simple and run two queries. 
One to set everything back to null
The second to set the active record to 'ja'

I'm guessing that there's probably a foreign key in the table too so that would be part of the update statement too.

As a matter of "style" I'd prefer to see an active column having a 1/0 or y/n type of value rather than using null all the time.

Comment: So like first running a query that sets everything to null and then make a function in php to run afterwards where the selected row gets set to the value 'ja' . or y/n - might be better yeah.

Comment: The important part is that only one row is "acitve"

Answer (score 1):

That is a complicated database design. The first thing that comes to mind is a trigger updating all other rows whenever a row gets 'ja'. However this will fail, because you cannot update the same table you are already updating.

It is generally a bad idea to design a table such that all rows must contain value y when one row contains value x. I would solve this with by removing the "active" column altogether and replace it with a one row table containing a column active_id. So there is always just one id active and the others are implicitely inactive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your database design, a possible update statement would be:

```
update mytable
set active = case when id = 123 then 'ja' else null end;
```

However the dbms doesn't guarantee that there will always be exactly one record with 'ja'. It's up to you to be careful about it.

PS: I agree with Sarah King on the NULL issue. NULL means "I don't know", but you know very well that the records are not active. So this should be a non-nullable column with values "ja" and "nein" or whatever you prefer. In MySQL you would rather use a BOOLEAN column.